# Mouse moves vertically on login

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mouse, login, login-screen

*OS X El Capitan 10.11.3 - USB mouse (steelseries Sensei)*

When trying to move the cursor, the movement is limited only to vertical direction. What could be the possible problem?

Comment: & it's fine once logged in?

Comment: Yes, it is for some reason

Comment: Does it use custom drivers? It's not a mouse I know.

Comment: Not really, no. There's a possibility to install custom software to change the profiles, colour, etc. but I am not using it.

Comment: I'd give it a try - might just make the difference. Otherwise, I've no ideas, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely answer is that something is installed or loaded at the user level that allows the mouse to function properly.

Can you try creating a fresh user and logging in as them and see if you get the same fixed result once you're logged in?

Alternately can you try another 3rd party external USB mouse to see if it experiences the same issue.

Comment: The issue appears on the logon screen and not after you login.

Comment: Got that, and you said it's resolved as soon as you login, I'm suggesting you isolate if it's resolved for all users or something specifically setup on your user.

Comment: Sorry I would have just added these suggestions as comments on the original post but SE doesn't let me do that until I establish my reputation a bit more